# Open WPF expander when item inside is selected

Tags: wpf, expander

I have an expander with items inside as follows:

```
Expander
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
```

The Expander is currently closed.

I select "Item 1" programmatically.

How can I get the parent Expander to also expand?

I'm using a ListBox, whose actual code is pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

Expander has a "IsExpanded" property. If you set this property to "TRUE", It'll be opened.

Comment: How can I retrieve the Expander, though? It's set during runtime via a style, so I can't explicitly know a "name" in advance.

Comment: Save expander as a variable like `Expander _myExpander = new Expander(..)`. Save this `_myExpander` variable during the process, you can reach this expander with using `_myExpander.IsExpanded = true;`

Comment: Cool! Where would you recommend I put this code? (what do you mean by "during the process"?

Comment: Define a variable OUTSIDE the functions INSIDE the class like `Expander _myExpander;` then set this variable when you want to create a Expander like `_myExpander = new Expander(...);` Now you can use this Expander `(_myExpander)` variable in all the functions that you want. If you share some of your code, I can help more.